# Angular Form Group validation Not working in Modal Pop Up

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am facing a very strange issue with Modal pop up form validation. Details as below.

1) Project has a base page where angular template is defined as below. It also has AG Grid

2) template loaded in the modal pop up is emailFailureActivityClosureTemplate. it is angular component.

3) Modal pop up is opened using

```
@ViewChild('emailFailureActivityClosureTemplate') elementEmailFailureClosureView: ElementRef;
```

this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(this.elementEmailFailureClosureView,config );

4) emailFailureActivityClosureTemplate is a simple form group with below HTML in component

Email Failure Activity Closure
        
            ×

```
  <div>

    <form [formGroup]="failureActivityClosureForm" (ngSubmit)="closeFailureActivity()" class="mycustomfrm" novalidate>

        <div class="container" style=" margin-top: 3%">

              <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-12" 

                      [ngClass]="{'has-error':(failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').touched || 
                      failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').dirty) && 
                      failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').valid}"

                      >
                        <label for="activityClosureComments" class="required-field">Closure Comments</label>


                       <textarea type="text" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': !failureActivityClosureForm.valid}" 
                          formControlName="closureComments" 
                          class="form-control form-control-md"                            
                          placeholder="Please enter closure comments."  [(ngModel)]="failureComments" >

                        </textarea>




                      <span *ngIf="(failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').touched || 
                      failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').dirty) &&
                      failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').errors">
                      <span *ngIf="failureActivityClosureForm.get('closureComments').errors.required" class="hasError">
                      Required
                      </span>
                      </span>

                      </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-right: 1%; padding-bottom: 2%">
                          <button class="btn btn-sm  pull-right cstm_cncl" type="button" (click)="onCancelClick()" style="margin-right: 11px;min-width: 85px;">
                              Cancel
                          </button>

                          <button class="btn btn-sm   btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" style="margin-right: 11px;min-width: 85px;"
                              [disabled]="!failureActivityClosureForm.valid">
                              Save Comments</button>
                      </div>
              </div>

        </div>       


    </form>

  </div>
```

5) Form validator is plugged in constructor as

constructor(private toastr: ToastrService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private _notificationService: NotificationHistoryService,private fb: FormBuilder)
    {

```
  this.failureActivityClosureForm = this.fb.group({

    closureComments: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],

  });

};
```

When the base page AG Grid is present without any scroll, the form validation in the pop up works fine. However , when the AG Grid columns in base page are resized, the validation in pop up stops working. This is very strange behaviour and i am not able to figure out the issue.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks 
Siddhesh

Comment: when you say validation pop up stops working, is it the validation that doesn't work or the pop up fails to open?

Comment: Pop up opens , but validation does not work. validation is done using reactive form component in pop up.

Comment: i was able to add a temporary fix by forcing a timeout when the pop up component is being loaded in NgAfterInit() event.